# Conversion From String to Clob and Clob to String

Tags: java, sql, string, clob

I am trying to save XML response which comes as StrignBuffer to method.
I need to save this string data to Sql as CLOB and retrieve the same.

The response can be upto 3-4Kb, which should be retrieved to StringBuffer again

Can any one give me tutorial or sample code which doesn't include db specific methods/jars.

I can change db column type if CLOB is not suitable or any other better alternative.

Please suggest.

Comment: I think for small strings you can just getString/setString, just like with VARCHAR2, and the driver will take care of it. With large strings, it gets messy. But 3~4KB should be okay (4000 bytes is the first hurdle).

Comment: First, unless you need synchronization, it's better practice to use *StringBuilder* which is not sync and WAY faster than *StrignBuffer*. Second, which *DB* are you working on ?

Comment: @alfasin: Given that a database is involved, the differences between StringBuffer and StringBuilder are likely to be entirely insignificant. Sure, it's worth using StringBuilder anyway - but let's not go overboard on emphasizing the performance benefits.

Comment: @JonSkeet Of course you're right (about I/O being much more expensive) :)   that's why I said "better practice" and not "you should". Further, I believe that today's middle-tier technologies (like hibernate) are "smart" enough to cache recently used data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `CLOB` by calling `connection.createClob()`, then you can populate it with methods such as `setString`, `setCharacterStream` or `setAsciiStream`.

Create a `PreparedStatement` and call its `setClob()` to store your CLOB in the databae.

Retrieving the data is just the same, read it from a `ResultSet` and call `getCharacterStream`, `getAsciiStream` or `getSubStream` on it.

Comment: I am using Spring JDBC for jdbc operations.

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatementCallback` and a `PreparedStatementCreator` then.

Answer (score 1):

For `NamedParameterJdbcTemplte`:

```
MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
paramSource.addValue("clob", "a long long text", Types.CLOB);
namedTemplate.update(INSERT_STMT, paramSource);
```

For `JdbcTemplate`:

```
<bean id="lobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler">
    <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor" ref="nativeJdbcExtractor"/>
</bean>
```

and:

```
private @Autowire LobHandler lobHandler;
jdbcTemplate.update("insert into customer(id,name,comments) "
    + "values (?, ?, ?)", new PreparedStatementSetter() {
  public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
    ps.setLong(1, 2L);
    ps.setString(2, "Jon");
    lobHandler.getLobCreator().setClobAsString(ps, 3, "Clob data");
  }
});
```

To extract String from `ResultSet`:

```
 inc.setDetail(lobHandler.getClobAsString(rs, "DETAIL"));
```

Look to official docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-lob